# ElasticSearch 5.2 shingles not produce results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm following official ElasticSearch [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/shingles.html#_producing_shingles)

I've created following index to have title and title.shingles (second one with custom analyzer that produces shingles with 2 words)

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,  
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "my_shingle_filter": {
                    "type":             "shingle",
                    "min_shingle_size": 2, 
                    "max_shingle_size": 2, 
                    "output_unigrams":  false   
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "my_shingle_analyzer": {
                    "type":             "custom",
                    "tokenizer":        "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "my_shingle_filter" 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT /my_index/_mapping/my_type
{
    "my_type": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "shingles": {
                        "type":     "text",
                        "analyzer": "my_shingle_analyzer",
                        "search_analyzer": "my_shingle_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And put some data in

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": 1 }}
{ "title": "Sue ate the alligator" }
{ "index": { "_id": 2 }}
{ "title": "The alligator ate Sue" }
{ "index": { "_id": 3 }}
{ "title": "Sue never goes anywhere without her alligator skin purse" }
```

Now I wanted to query based on title.shingles field
This produces result:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
   "query": {
        "match": {
           "title.shingles": "ate sue"
        }
   }
}
```

This does not produce result (empty result set)

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
   "query": {
        "match": {
           "title.shingles": "the hungry alligator ate sue"
        }
   }
}
```

Seems like my_shingle_analyzer is not applied when searching? My assumption is that it should and the long text should be 'tokenized' and one of these tokens should be found ...

I've verified that analyzer works by using ES analyze command

```
GET /my_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_shingle_analyzer
{
"text": "Sue ate the alligator"
}
```

Comment: When doing the second query, I get a result containing the second document, which seems correct to me since it matches on the shingle `ate sue`

Comment: If second query ("the hungry alligator ate sue") produces results for you (which I would expect) - then I'm lost - as I'm getting empty result set ... I'm using ES 5.2.0

Comment: Can you show what you get with `GET my_index` after the index is created?

Comment: Part 1 {
  "my_index": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "shingles": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_shingle_analyzer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },

Comment: Part 2 "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "provided_name": "my_index",
        "creation_date": "1486652751401",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "my_shingle_filter": {
              "max_shingle_size": "2",
              "min_shingle_size": "2",
              "output_unigrams": "false",
              "type": "shingle"
            }
          },

Comment: Part 3  "analyzer": {
            "my_shingle_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "my_shingle_filter"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "4fTcT4DjRVKyQy8vymTmEw",
        "version": {
          "created": "5020099"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: You should have updated your question, but thanks :-)

Comment: Interesting, that works on ES 2.4, but I get the same result as you on ES 5.2, at least this is consistent... Investigating further...

Comment: @Val did you identify the issue here? This is similar to the issue I have reported at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415512/elasticsearch-shingles-not-working-with-odd-no-of-search-words

Comment: @moyukhbera I'm still working on this one ;-)