# Elasticsearch: Shingles not working with odd no. of search words

Tags: elasticsearch

When trying to search with odd no. of words with my shingle analyzer no result shows up.

'**new delhi abcd**' does not return any results but '**new delhi abcd xyz**' returns

My analyzers look like below

```
{
    "search": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "my_shingle_filter": {
                            "max_shingle_size": "2",
                            "min_shingle_size": "2",
                            "output_unigrams": "false",
                            "type": "shingle"
                        },
                        "autocomplete_filter": {
                            "type": "edge_ngram",
                            "min_gram": "1",
                            "max_gram": "40"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "my_shingle_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "my_shingle_filter"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                        },
                        "shingle_with_autocomplete": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "my_shingle_filter",
                                "autocomplete_filter"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The mapping for the type is shared below

```
{
    "search": {
        "mappings": {
            "address": {
                "properties": {
                    "full_address": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "norms": false,
                        "fields": {
                            "edge_n_grams": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "norms": false,
                                "analyzer": "autocomplete"
                            },
                            "shingles": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "norms": false,
                                "analyzer": "shingle_with_autocomplete"
                            },
                            "synonym": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "norms": false,
                                "analyzer": "synonym_autocomplete"
                            }
                        },
                        "analyzer": "whitespace"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Query 1

```
GET search/address/_search?_source=full_address
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "full_address.shingles": {
                "query": "new delhi",
                "analyzer": "my_shingle_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Results

```
{
    ...
    "hits": {
        "total": 21801,
        "max_score": 8.015874,
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "search",
                "_type": "address",
                "_id": "581c50297fd84ecc35420570",
                "_score": 8.015874,
                "_source": {
                    "full_address": "new delhi nagar palika adarsh vidyalay new delhi nagar palika adarsh vidyalay tilak lane tilak marg area new delhi delhi 110001"
                }
            }, {
                "_index": "search",
                "_type": "address",
                "_id": "581c502a7fd84ecc35422010",
                "_score": 7.013889,
                "_source": {
                    "full_address": "kingdom hall of jehovant witness gyan bharti public school saket new delhi new delhi delhi 110017"
                }
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

### Query 2

```
GET search/address/_search?_source=full_address
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "full_address.shingles": {
                "query": "new delhi nag",
                "analyzer": "my_shingle_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Results

```
{
  ...,
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

'**new delhi nagar pal**' returns proper results.

Any help/insights would be appreciated

Comment: You need to increase `max_shingle_size` to at least three, otherwise you only have shingles composed of two tokens and not three.

Comment: when searching for `new delhi abcd` there's no way to retrieve any results since you have shingles with either `new delhi` or `delhi abdc`

Comment: At query time I have used **my_shingle_analyzer** which breaks the query text into word bigrams before matching. I have checked the analyzer output for both indexed doc & search query. It looks fine to me

Comment: I'll get back to you shortly, unless someone else finds the issue in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23346) in ES 5.2.x. Issue is with the single filter in new version